# Movie Identification: 1980/1990's sci-fi with people on a spaceship getting killed in cryosleep/Virtual reality

Tags: story-identification, movie

Key facts about the movie:

- Late 80's to mid 90's. I think I watched it about 20 years ago around 1995 +/- 5 years.
- Sci-fi
- Either involved cryo-sleep or virtual reality sequences where the crewmembers lived out their fantasies and ended up getting killed during these sequences.
- These sequences included one in the wild west and one on a beach somewhere
- Cheesy and certainly not big budget. Possibly direct video.
- Lots of nudity, either a showerscene or bathtub or something similar. I would guess this means the movie has an age restriction but was certainly not a softcore movie.
- The crew were either prisoners or perhaps soldiers. These VR sequences where to either pass the time due to a long space flight or got injected into their cryopods by a killer/evil AI (think HAL).
- A gunfight with lasers towards the start of the movie.
- The name of the movie was possibly one word

I have gone through the entire list of sci-fi movies on imdb for the 80's and 90's and still didn't find it so it has to be pretty obscure. Thanks for any help, I never saw the end of the movie and I think about it every few years or so.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: Alien Intruder (1993) - DVD Cover]

[**Alien Intruder** (1993)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106244)

> Set in the year 2022, a group of convicts sentenced to life in prison
>   are led on a **mission into uncharted deep space** by Commander Skyler
>   to salvage a lost ship.

[image: Alien Intruder (1993) - Pic 01]

> As incentive to go on this dangerous mission, the convicts are given
>   the opportunity to **spend their weekends in a virtual reality world**
>   where they could **live out their sexual fantasies** with any woman
>   they choose.

[image: Alien Intruder (1993) - Pic 02]

> However, **a woman who is not part of the program appears in it**,
>   kills each virtual woman and seduces each convict. When she begins to
>   appear outside the program, the men quickly turn on each other.

<sup>*~ Movie synopsis from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Intruder); Stills from [KinoPoisk](http://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/9184/stills/)*</sup>

Comment: thanks mate. I am almost certain that is it i will have to watch it :) MY guess is I never found it because I was looking for a movie with a single word and I never remembered such a memorable person as billy dee williams could ever be in it.

Comment: Glad to help :-) I can assure you that all the scenes you described are in it. Happy Viewing!

Comment: @user23565 Billy Dee Williams makes any movie good.